# Ferris Wheel Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

One of the largest ferris wheel ever built is in the british airways london eye which was completed in 2000. The diameter is 135 m and passengers get on at the bottom 4 m above the ground. The wheel rotates once every three minutes.

a)  Draw a graph which represents the height of a passenger in metres as a function of time in minutes.

b)  Determine the equation that expresses your height h  as  a function of elapsed time t

c)  How high is a passenger 5 minutes after the wheel starts rotating?

d) How many seconds after the wheel starts rotating is a passenger 85 m above the ground
              for the first time. Answer to the nearest tenth.

Please help me solve this equation and try and making to as clear as possible my solution lacks.

Comment: The equation of the height is :

h(t) = h₀ + A sin(θ(t) + φ) ; where :

h₀ is the height of the centre of the wheel ; h₀ = 4 + 135/2 = 71.5 m ;

A is the amplitude ( the extreme values with respect to the 
centre of the wheel) ; A = 67.5 m ;

T being the period ; T = 3 min = 180 s , so 

θ(t) = ωt = 2πt/T = πt/90 , ( where ω is angular frequency ω = 2π/T) ;

φ is the phase shift , since the motion starts at the bottom φ = -π/2 ;

Now the equation is :

h(t) = 71.5 + 67.5 sin(πt/90 - π/2) = 71.5 + 67.5 sin π(t-45)/90

Comment: Please, edit the title to something better.

Comment: This question almost makes me want to make an animated GIF of a Ferris wheel and post that as an answer.

Comment: user76459, could you edit your question to put your partial solution into it, with line breaks and things? It's very hard to read.

Comment: c) 5 min = 300 s , so 

h(300) = 105.25 m

d) h = 85 m , so sin π(t-45)/90 = (85 - 71.5)/67.5 ==>

t = 45+ (90/π) sin⁻¹ 0.2 = 50.77 sec

Comment: dfuser :) that would be sick anything that could layout the ansers for me I'am supposed to graph it though

Comment: if someone could show me a full solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is on the right track.  The question asks you to use time in minutes, so you should not convert to seconds.  In that case $\omega=\frac {2\pi}3$  That changes your constant $45$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is a straightforward question and I strongly suggest that you go over your textbook or at least one of these following resources:

- [Putrplemath](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/grphtrig.htm)
- [RIT Notes](https://www.rit.edu/~w-asc/documents/services/resources/handouts/17Graphs%20of%20Trig%20Function.pdf)
- [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry/basic-trigonometry/trig_graphs_tutorial/v/we-amplitude-and-period)

After that, try the problem again, checking against the answer below:

a)

[image]

b) $h(t) =\frac{135}{2} \sin(\frac{2 \pi}{3}x - \frac{\pi}{2}) + \frac{135}{2} + 4 = \frac{135}{2} \cos(\frac{2 \pi}{3}x + \pi) + \frac{135}{2} + 4$.

c) $h(5) = 105.25$ feet.

d) $h^{-1}(85) = 50.77 $ seconds.

Because you did not attempt to solve the problem yourself, I will not provide a detailed solution. If you run into trouble trying to complete the problem yourself, let me know in a comment and I may be able to help.